# How do I find the frequency of a specific value in an array?

Tags: c++

I'm a newbie in C++ programming and I'm following this book called jumping into C++ by Alex Allain, there's a tic-tac-toe exercise in the book and I'm having a hard time completing that exercise, so far what I've done is to prompt user to enter X or O value, which get stored in a 2d array, I want to track if for example char X appeared 3 times in the array, so far I use counter++ but it only increment once. below is the source of what I've done so far hopefully it will make my question much more clearer and let me know as well how I'm doing in terms of the way my codes look such as its structure and functions:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "string"

using namespace std;

void display_array(char array[][3]);
void check_input(char array[][3], int input);
void check_winner(char array[][3]);
int check_x(char array[][3]);
int check_o(char array[][3]);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char array[3][3];
    int counter = 0;

    for(int row = 0; row < 3; row++){

        cout << "\n";

        for(int col = 0; col < 3; col++){
            counter++;
            array[row][col] = counter;
        }
    }

    display_array(array);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void display_array(char array[][3]){

    int position_input;
    string symbol_input;

    do{

    for(int i=0; i < 3; i++){

        for(int j=0; j < 3; j++){
            cout << " [ ";
            cout << array[i][j];
            cout << " ] ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

    cout << "Position: ";
    cin >> position_input;

    check_input(array, position_input);


    }while(position_input != 0);
} 

void check_input(char array[][3], int input)
{
    char user_input = input;

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            if(user_input == array[i][j])
            {
                cout << "array[" << i << "][" << j << "] replace with: ";
                cin >> array[i][j];

            }   

        }
    }
    check_winner(array);
}
void check_winner(char array[][3]){
    cout << check_x(array);

    if(check_x(array) == 3){
        cout << check_x(array);
    }

    else if(check_o(array) == true){
        cout << "o";
    }

}
int check_x(char array[][3]){
    int counter, x[3];
    counter = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            if(array[i][j] == array[i][j]){
                counter++;
            }
            x[i] = counter;
            return x[i];
        }
    }

}
int  check_o(char array[][3]){

    int counter;
    counter = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            if(array[i][j] == 'o'){
                counter++;
                return counter;
            }else{
                return counter;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Rojee: Please keep in mind that C++ is different from C and C#, which are different from each other.  The similar names are confusing, but they're distinct enough that programmers in one may not be able to help with the others.

Comment: I am aware of that and I apologize.

Comment: It seems that your major problem is you seem to be unaware of scoping and how functions work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bunch of little problems but the most immediate one seems to be this kind of thing:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
        if(array[i][j] == 'o'){
            counter++;
            return counter;
        }else{
            return counter;
        }
    }
}
```

Regardless of whether the element tested is an 'o' or not you are going to return after one loop.  Change it to something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
        if(array[i][j] == 'o')
            counter++;
    }
}

return counter;
```

Comment: Yes but people aren't horses.  Normally they have to learn to walk before running.

Answer (score 0):

**My Answer:**

Last part of the question first: The coding looks good, I would be happy if you would have commented some of the operations even if the program is very compelling (// /* */).

In my opinion is your question a little bit missleading in terms of solving the exercise. I thought of your way at first in the same way. The problem is that the pattern is not just detected by a frequency of 3 because it would allow wrong checking pattern. To make it visual:

```cpp
7 8 9
4 5 6
1 2 3
```

f.e. the frequency of 3 like 1,2,5 or 9 6 5 are not a correct answer but - 1 5 9 are. And even if you calculate every single frequency pattern - it would be much more coding than the solution I found that is defined in the following blog of my solution:

```cpp
    status_check = possibilities(field,player,2,0,1,1,0,2); //diagonal 1 5 9
    status_check = possibilities(field,player,0,0,1,1,2,2); //diagonal 7 5 3
    status_check = possibilities(field,player,0,0,1,0,2,0); //vertical 7 4 1
    status_check = possibilities(field,player,0,1,1,1,2,1); //vertical 8 5 2
    status_check = possibilities(field,player,0,2,1,2,2,2); //vertical 9 6 3
    status_check = possibilities(field,player,0,0,0,1,0,2); //horizontal 7 8 9
    status_check = possibilities(field,player,1,0,1,1,1,2); //horizontal 4 5 5
    status_check = possibilities(field,player,2,0,2,1,2,2); //horizontal 1 2 3
```

*That is how I figured that exercise out playable with the num pad.(I am really proud of that piece of code. :-) )

I love that book by the way but I sadly couldn't figure out that one:
"Bonus: can you make your program detect if the game cannot be won
by either side before the entire grid is filled?"
But if anyone hops over that chapter - this solution will help for sure:*

*The exercise is like follows* (Page 121, Jump to Cpp):

> Write a small tic-tac-toe program that allows two players to play
>   tic-tac-toe competitively. Your program should check to see if either
>   player has won, or if the board is filled completely (with the game
>   ending in a tie). Bonus: can you make your program detect if the game
>   cannot be won by either side before the entire grid is filled?

The following code can be simple compiled and executed with c++ 17 standard and all librarys should be available with gcc (GCC) 8.2.1

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits> //just for the input validation

using namespace std;

int input_check(char field[3][3],char player);
void display_field(char field[3][3],int size);
void initialize_field(char field[3][3],int size,char player);
string win_check(char field[3][3],char player,int size);
int code(char field[3][3],int i,int j,char player);
int possibilities(char field[3][3],char player,int a,int aa,int b,int bb,int c,int cc);

int main()
{
  char field[3][3];
  int size = 3;
  char player ='-';

  initialize_field(field,size,player);
  display_field(field,size);

  while (field[0][0]!='w')
    {
      player = 'X';
      input_check(field,player);
      system("clear");
      display_field(field,size);
      cout << win_check(field,player,size);

      if (field[0][0] =='w')
      {
        cout << endl;
        break;
      }
      player = 'O';
      input_check(field,player);
      system("clear");
      display_field(field,size);
      cout << win_check(field,player,size);

      if (field[0][0] =='w')
      {
        cout << endl;
        break;
      }
    }
return 0;
}


void initialize_field(char field[3][3],int size,char player)
{
  int i,k;
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
      for (k = 0; k < size; k++)
        {
          field[i][k]= player;
        }
    }
}

int input_check(char field[3][3],char player)
{
  int input = 0;
  bool def = false;
  while (def != true)
  {
    while(!(cin >> input))
      {  //check the Input format for integer the right way
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cout << "Invalid input.  Try again: ";
      }
    switch (input)
    {
      case 1:{
        def = code(field,2,0,player);
        break;}
      case 2:{
        def = code(field,2,1,player);
        break;}
      case 3:{
        def = code(field,2,2,player);
        break;}
      case 4:{
        def = code(field,1,0,player);
        break;}
      case 5:{
        def = code(field,1,1,player);
        break;}
      case 6:{
        def = code(field,1,2,player);
        break;}
      case 7:{
        def = code(field,0,0,player);
        break;}
      case 8:{
        def = code(field,0,1,player);
        break;}
      case 9:{
        def = code(field,0,2,player);
        break;}
      default:{
        cout << "Invalid input.  Try again: " << endl;
        break;}
    }
  }
/*
7 8 9   00 01 02
4 5 6   10 11 12
1 2 3   20 21 22
*/
  return input;
}

int code(char field[3][3],int i,int j,char player)
{
  int def=0;
  if (field[i][j]=='-')
    {
      field[i][j]=player;
      def = true;
    }
  else
    {
      cout << "Invalid input.  Try again: " << endl;
    }
  return def;
}

void display_field(char field[3][3],int size)
{
  int i,k;
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
      for (k = 0; k < size; k++)
        {
          cout << field[i][k];
          cout << " ";
            if (k==2) //seperate with new line after the third k
              {
                cout << endl;
              }
        }
    }
}

string win_check(char field[3][3],char player,int size)
{
  string status;
  int status_check;

  /*
  7 8 9   00 01 02
  4 5 6   10 11 12
  1 2 3   20 21 22
  */

  if ((field[0][0]!='-')&&(field[0][1]!='-')&&(field[0][2]!='-') &&(field[1][0]!='-')&&(field[1][1]!='-')&&(field[1][2]!='-')&&(field[2][0]!='-')&&(field[2][1]!='-')&&(field[2][2]!='-'))
    {
      status = "Rien ne va plus - Nichts geht mehr meine Lieben. Unentschieden";
      field[0][0]='w';
    }

    status_check = possibilities(field,player,2,0,1,1,0,2); //diagonal 1 5 9
    status_check = possibilities(field,player,0,0,1,1,2,2); //diagonal 7 5 3
    status_check = possibilities(field,player,0,0,1,0,2,0); //vertical 7 4 1
    status_check = possibilities(field,player,0,1,1,1,2,1); //vertical 8 5 2
    status_check = possibilities(field,player,0,2,1,2,2,2); //vertical 9 6 3
    status_check = possibilities(field,player,0,0,0,1,0,2); //horizontal 7 8 9
    status_check = possibilities(field,player,1,0,1,1,1,2); //horizontal 4 5 5
    status_check = possibilities(field,player,2,0,2,1,2,2); //horizontal 1 2 3

    if (status_check == true)
    {
      status = "Player " + string(1, player) + " won!!";
      field[0][0] ='w';
    }
return status;
}

int possibilities(char field[3][3],char player,int a,int aa,int b,int bb,int c,int cc)
{
  int status;

  if ((field[a][aa]==player)&&(field[b][bb]==player)&&(field[c][cc]==player))
  {
    status = true;
  }


  return status;
}
```

Comment: I didn't check if the answer is correct. But even if the code is correct, then, in my opinion, it still misses the point of a Q&A platform, because an answer should explain what the OP is doing wrong in the shown code. You at least should tell why you think that your solution solves the problem in a better way than the one of the OP.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Valid point - I was so excited to post my first answer, I forgot the most important part. I edit it, thank you.